# C Dll Import throws Marshall Directive Exception in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I have a problem including a DLL (written in C) in my C# project and I hope you can help me. In my research I found the DLLImport, but I'm not sure which types the C variables convert to...

The C method from the DLL I want to import is the following:

```
int lou_translateString (
     const char * tableList,
     const widechar * inbuf,
     int *inlen,
     widechar *outbuf,
     int *outlen,
     char *typeform,
     char *spacing,
     int mode);
```

This is the DLLImport I tried:

```
[DllImport("liblouis-2.dll", EntryPoint = "lou_translateString", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public static extern int translate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        String tableList,
        String inbuf,
        int inlen,
        String outbuf,
        int outlen,
        String typeform,
        String spacing,
        int mode);
```

But when I try to call the method I get:

MarshallDirectiveException
Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination
(Int32/UInt32 must be paired with I4 or U4)

Can anyone help with the exception? I'm pretty sure it has to do with the types of the parameters in the method, but I don't know how to declare them right. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance
Alex

Added shorted Documentation for clarification

> This function takes a string of 16-bit Unicode characters in inbuf and
>   translates it into a string of 16-bit characters in outbuf.
>
> The tableList parameter points to a list of translation tables
>   separated by commas.
>
> Note that both the *inlen and *outlen parameters are pointers to
>   integers. When the function is called, these integers contain the
>   maximum input and output lengths, respectively. When it returns, they
>   are set to the actual lengths used.
>
> The typeform parameter is used to indicate italic type, boldface type,
>   computer braille, etc. It is a string of characters with the same
>   length as the input buffer pointed to by *inbuf. However, it is used
>   to pass back character-by-character results, so enough space must be
>   provided to match the *outlen parameter. Each character indicates the
>   typeform of the corresponding character in the input buffer. The
>   values are as follows: 0 plain-text; 1 italic; 2 bold; 4 underline; 8
>   computer braille. These values can be added for multiple emphasis. If
>   this parameter is NULL, no checking for type forms is done. In
>   addition, if this parameter is not NULL, it is set on return to have
>   an 8 at every position corresponding to a character in outbuf which
>   was defined to have a dot representation containing dot 7, dot 8 or
>   both, and to 0 otherwise.
>
> The spacing parameter is used to indicate differences in spacing
>   between the input string and the translated output string. It is also
>   of the same length as the string pointed to by *inbuf. If this
>   parameter is NULL, no spacing information is computed.
>
> The mode parameter specifies how the translation should be done.
>
> The function returns 1 if no errors were encountered and 0 if a
>   complete translation could not be done.

This is what I wrote to test the function in Main:

```
        StringBuilder outbuf = new StringBuilder("Test", 30);
        int inlength = 100;
        int louint = 0;
        int outlength = 100;
        String inbuf = "test";


        louint = lou_translateString("de-de-g1.ctb", inbuf, inlen: ref inlength, outbuf: outbuf, outlen: ref outlength, typeform: null, spacing: null, mode: 8);
```

But at the end the original outbuf is not changed at all. Would you say the parameters are right? Do I have to modify the outbuf parameter somehow as it is a StringBuilder and not just a String ( outbuf.Replace() )?

Comment: The return value is `int` not string should pair with I4 like the error said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value `MarshalAs` was just wrong. The return value is `int` and not a string. That explains the error, but there is more. The rest of your pinvoke declaration has errors. I would do it like this:

```
[DllImport("liblouis-2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int lou_translateString(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    string tableList,
    string inbuf,
    ref int inlen,
    StringBuilder outbuf,
    ref int outlen,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    StringBuilder typeform,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    StringBuilder spacing,
    int mode
);
```

The text buffers that are marshalled out of the function must be declared as `StringBuilder`. And you had some other errors. Translate `int*` as `ref int`.

In order to call the function you need to create a new instance of `StringBuilder` to pass as the `outbuf` parameter. You'll have to work out how large the buffer needs to be. I assume that the documentation for the function tells you how to do that. At least for initial testing you can pass `null` for `typeform` and `spacing`.

Comment: Alright fixed the error, thanks. Typeform and spacing are parameters which are most likely set to 'null' so I'm not that worried about that. I'm having more trouble with the ref int parameters, because I can't declare the pointer in my safe context to use it as a parameter. Do you have any ideas how to fix that? I added the description so you can get an idea of what it's about.

Comment: The ref params are fine as per my answer. The marshaller will pass pointers. At least for initial testing you can pass `null` for `typeform` and `spacing`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you are not passing the right length parameters: `inlength` is 4 and `outlength` is 30. What is the return value? You assigned it to `louint`. What is the value?

Comment: Oh ok thought the lengths should be the maximum lengths of the integers. The lou_translateString function returns 1 if no errors were encountered and 0 if a complete translation could not be done. Well it returns 0 so theres clearly a problem but I don't know where. I just assigned it to louint to test it against 0 or 1 later on.

Comment: I think you are now beyond the scope of the original question. I believe I answered that. If I were you I would now build a C++ project that called the function. Prove that works and remove any pinvoke interop concerns from the equation. Once you have a set of params that are known to work in C++, try again in C#.

Comment: Alright thanks alot, you are right, your PInvoke tips were spot on, will try that.